# C#.NET File download only works in IE

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-applications

I have a page in my site which generates a PDF report dynamically on the server whilst displaying a "please wait" message to the users browser. After it has finished it puts the unique filepath in the session and then opens up download.aspx which is empty bar the following c# code in the page_load function.

```
    string fileUID = (string)(Session["fileUID"]);
        string FilePath = @fileUID;
        byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath);
        string sFileName = "Report.pdf";

        System.Web.HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.ClearHeaders();
        context.Response.ClearContent();
        context.Response.AppendHeader("content-length", fileBytes.Length.ToString());
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        context.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + sFileName);
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes);
        context.Response.Flush();
        System.IO.File.Delete(FilePath);
        context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

In IE this brings up the download dialogue allowing the user to download the file. However in chrome, firefox and safari it just sits on the please wait page forever...

I have also tried specifying the mime type for a PDF file, and not specifying content-disposition to make the PDF display in the browser window, again works perfectly in internet explorer but not any other browser.

The issue occurs both when testing on localhost, and when uploaded to the server.

I have searched both on here and the wider world and cannot seem to find anybody else with the same issue.

Please can somebody show me the error of my ways.

Comment: is the please wait dialog on the client. Do you have code that you can show us?

Comment: Look at the actual network requests made. The posted code is likely irrelevant - I suspect that FF/Chrome *never make* the secondary request after the "Please wait..".

Comment: Whether the pdf is shown in the browser or in Acrobat Reader depends on the browser. In IE it is standard to display PDF files with the acrobat plugin, other browsers probably need to be configured to do that. (Which is the better approach, I **hate** it when my PDF downloads are displayed in the browser. **hate it!!!**)

Comment: thanks all, the function in my please wait page was incorrect so as suggested it was never actually calling the download page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help.

The problem was with the please wait dialogue page, I debugged it in the other browsers and they all hate window.location(page) so I changed it to window.open(page) and it works fine.

No idea how I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

this 's how I do

```
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";//check your valid file type
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + targetFileName);
    Response.Charset = "";

    using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Response.OutputStream)
    {
        //writer.Write(contentBytes);
    }
    Response.Flush();
    Response.Close();
    Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Make sure all stream are closed or disposed before CompletedRequest() called.

Comment: thanks, id messed up the previous page so my function was never being called

Answer (score 0):

you should set cookie when file created be done like this:

```
 var cookie = new HttpCookie("fileDownloadToken", _token);
                    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10); 
                    cookie.Path = "/"; //Also set path
                    context.Response.AppendCookie(cookie);
```

and the next page with jquery.cookie plugin read cookie value if set it to a Expected value then unblock ui with jquery blockui:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var fileDownloadCheckTimer;
    function blockUIForDownload() {
        var token = '1357.11.22'; 
        $('#download_token_value').val(token);
       $.blockUI({
            message:$('#domMessage'),
            css: {
                padding: 10,
                margin: 0,
                width: '30%',
                top: '50%',
                left: '35%',

                textAlign: 'center',
                color: '#000',
                border: '3px solid #aaa',
                backgroundColor: '#fff',
                cursor: 'wait',
            }});
            fileDownloadCheckTimer = window.setInterval(function () {
                var cookieValue = $.cookie('fileDownloadToken');
                //alert(cookieValue);
                if (cookieValue == token)
                    finishDownload();
            }, 1000);
    }

    function finishDownload() {
        window.clearInterval(fileDownloadCheckTimer);
        $.unblockUI();
        $.cookie('fileDownloadToken', null, { path: '/' });

    }

</script>
```